# Apache RewriteRule [L] not being honoured

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla, url-rewriting

In a Joomla website with SEF enabled, I have keyword friendly urls, such as /keyword/keyword. I need to rewrite all urls that start with index.php, such as /index.php/keyword/keyword

I have tried adding a conditional RewriteRule both after and before the core .htaccess rules coming with Joomla:

```
## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#
## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.


#rewrite all urls starting with index.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.php
RewriteRule ^index.php(.*?)$ /$1 [R=302,L]
```

Here is the rewritelog:

```
[Tue Jun 23 11:19:35.986104 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 25526] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:40592] 127.0.0.1 - - [acgwebsite.example.com/sid#7f483be32210][rid#7f48292070a0/initial] [perdir /home/jochen/projects/acgwebsite/trunk/] strip per-dir prefix: /home/jochen/projects/acgwebsite/trunk/nz/nzic -> nz/nzic
[Tue Jun 23 11:19:35.986118 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 25526] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:40592] 127.0.0.1 - - [acgwebsite.example.com/sid#7f483be32210][rid#7f48292070a0/initial] [perdir /home/jochen/projects/acgwebsite/trunk/] applying pattern '.*' to uri 'nz/nzic'
[Tue Jun 23 11:19:35.986137 2015] [rewrite:trace5] [pid 25526] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:40592] 127.0.0.1 - - [acgwebsite.example.com/sid#7f483be32210][rid#7f48292070a0/initial] setting env variable 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION' to ''
[Tue Jun 23 11:19:35.986150 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 25526] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:40592] 127.0.0.1 - - [acgwebsite.example.com/sid#7f483be32210][rid#7f48292070a0/initial] [perdir /home/jochen/projects/acgwebsite/trunk/] add path info postfix: /home/jochen/projects/acgwebsite/trunk/nz -> /home/jochen/projects/acgwebsite/trunk/nz/nzic
[Tue Jun 23 11:19:35.986162 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 25526] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:40592] 127.0.0.1 - - [acgwebsite.example.com/sid#7f483be32210][rid#7f48292070a0/initial] [perdir /home/jochen/projects/acgwebsite/trunk/] strip per-dir prefix: /home/jochen/projects/acgwebsite/trunk/nz/nzic -> nz/nzic
[Tue Jun 23 11:19:35.986177 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 25526] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:40592] 127.0.0.1 - - [acgwebsite.example.com/sid#7f483be32210][rid#7f48292070a0/initial] [perdir /home/jochen/projects/acgwebsite/trunk/] applying pattern '.*' to uri 'nz/nzic'
[Tue Jun 23 11:19:35.986192 2015] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 25526] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:40592] 127.0.0.1 - - [acgwebsite.example.com/sid#7f483be32210][rid#7f48292070a0/initial] [perdir /home/jochen/projects/acgwebsite/trunk/] RewriteCond: input='/nz/nzic' pattern='!^/index\\.php' => matched
[Tue Jun 23 11:19:35.986215 2015] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 25526] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:40592] 127.0.0.1 - - [acgwebsite.example.com/sid#7f483be32210][rid#7f48292070a0/initial] [perdir /home/jochen/projects/acgwebsite/trunk/] RewriteCond: input='/home/jochen/projects/acgwebsite/trunk/nz' pattern='!-f' => matched
[Tue Jun 23 11:19:35.986234 2015] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 25526] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:40592] 127.0.0.1 - - [acgwebsite.example.com/sid#7f483be32210][rid#7f48292070a0/initial] [perdir /home/jochen/projects/acgwebsite/trunk/] RewriteCond: input='/home/jochen/projects/acgwebsite/trunk/nz' pattern='!-d' => matched
[Tue Jun 23 11:19:35.986246 2015] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 25526] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:40592] 127.0.0.1 - - [acgwebsite.example.com/sid#7f483be32210][rid#7f48292070a0/initial] [perdir /home/jochen/projects/acgwebsite/trunk/] rewrite 'nz/nzic' -> 'index.php'
[Tue Jun 23 11:19:35.986262 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 25526] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:40592] 127.0.0.1 - - [acgwebsite.example.com/sid#7f483be32210][rid#7f48292070a0/initial] [perdir /home/jochen/projects/acgwebsite/trunk/] add per-dir prefix: index.php -> /home/jochen/projects/acgwebsite/trunk/index.php
[Tue Jun 23 11:19:35.986277 2015] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 25526] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:40592] 127.0.0.1 - - [acgwebsite.example.com/sid#7f483be32210][rid#7f48292070a0/initial] [perdir /home/jochen/projects/acgwebsite/trunk/] strip document_root prefix: /home/jochen/projects/acgwebsite/trunk/index.php -> /index.php
[Tue Jun 23 11:19:35.986291 2015] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 25526] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:40592] 127.0.0.1 - - [acgwebsite.example.com/sid#7f483be32210][rid#7f48292070a0/initial] [perdir /home/jochen/projects/acgwebsite/trunk/] internal redirect with /index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[Tue Jun 23 11:19:35.986353 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 25526] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:40592] 127.0.0.1 - - [acgwebsite.example.com/sid#7f483be32210][rid#7f4829214bf8/initial/redir#1] [perdir /home/jochen/projects/acgwebsite/trunk/] strip per-dir prefix: /home/jochen/projects/acgwebsite/trunk/index.php -> index.php
[Tue Jun 23 11:19:35.986385 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 25526] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:40592] 127.0.0.1 - - [acgwebsite.example.com/sid#7f483be32210][rid#7f4829214bf8/initial/redir#1] [perdir /home/jochen/projects/acgwebsite/trunk/] applying pattern '.*' to uri 'index.php'
[Tue Jun 23 11:19:35.986403 2015] [rewrite:trace5] [pid 25526] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:40592] 127.0.0.1 - - [acgwebsite.example.com/sid#7f483be32210][rid#7f4829214bf8/initial/redir#1] setting env variable 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION' to ''
[Tue Jun 23 11:19:35.986420 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 25526] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:40592] 127.0.0.1 - - [acgwebsite.example.com/sid#7f483be32210][rid#7f4829214bf8/initial/redir#1] [perdir /home/jochen/projects/acgwebsite/trunk/] strip per-dir prefix: /home/jochen/projects/acgwebsite/trunk/index.php -> index.php
[Tue Jun 23 11:19:35.986432 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 25526] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:40592] 127.0.0.1 - - [acgwebsite.example.com/sid#7f483be32210][rid#7f4829214bf8/initial/redir#1] [perdir /home/jochen/projects/acgwebsite/trunk/] applying pattern '.*' to uri 'index.php'
[Tue Jun 23 11:19:35.986450 2015] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 25526] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:40592] 127.0.0.1 - - [acgwebsite.example.com/sid#7f483be32210][rid#7f4829214bf8/initial/redir#1] [perdir /home/jochen/projects/acgwebsite/trunk/] RewriteCond: input='/index.php' pattern='!^/index\\.php' => not-matched
[Tue Jun 23 11:19:35.986463 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 25526] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:40592] 127.0.0.1 - - [acgwebsite.example.com/sid#7f483be32210][rid#7f4829214bf8/initial/redir#1] [perdir /home/jochen/projects/acgwebsite/trunk/] strip per-dir prefix: /home/jochen/projects/acgwebsite/trunk/index.php -> index.php
[Tue Jun 23 11:19:35.986478 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 25526] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:40592] 127.0.0.1 - - [acgwebsite.example.com/sid#7f483be32210][rid#7f4829214bf8/initial/redir#1] [perdir /home/jochen/projects/acgwebsite/trunk/] applying pattern '^index.php(.*?)$' to uri 'index.php'
[Tue Jun 23 11:19:35.986495 2015] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 25526] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:40592] 127.0.0.1 - - [acgwebsite.example.com/sid#7f483be32210][rid#7f4829214bf8/initial/redir#1] [perdir /home/jochen/projects/acgwebsite/trunk/] RewriteCond: input='/index.php' pattern='^/index.php' => matched
[Tue Jun 23 11:19:35.986511 2015] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 25526] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:40592] 127.0.0.1 - - [acgwebsite.example.com/sid#7f483be32210][rid#7f4829214bf8/initial/redir#1] [perdir /home/jochen/projects/acgwebsite/trunk/] rewrite 'index.php' -> '/'
[Tue Jun 23 11:19:35.986527 2015] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 25526] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:40592] 127.0.0.1 - - [acgwebsite.example.com/sid#7f483be32210][rid#7f4829214bf8/initial/redir#1] [perdir /home/jochen/projects/acgwebsite/trunk/] explicitly forcing redirect with http://acgwebsite.example.com/
[Tue Jun 23 11:19:35.986540 2015] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 25526] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:40592] 127.0.0.1 - - [acgwebsite.example.com/sid#7f483be32210][rid#7f4829214bf8/initial/redir#1] [perdir /home/jochen/projects/acgwebsite/trunk/] escaping http://acgwebsite.example.com/ for redirect
[Tue Jun 23 11:19:35.986554 2015] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 25526] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:40592] 127.0.0.1 - - [acgwebsite.example.com/sid#7f483be32210][rid#7f4829214bf8/initial/redir#1] [perdir /home/jochen/projects/acgwebsite/trunk/] redirect to http://acgwebsite.example.com/ [REDIRECT/302]
```

It seems the [L] on the first rewrite is being ignored and the 2nd rewrite is executed regardless. How can I fix this?

To clarify what I expect to happen:

```
http://test.com/index.php/keyword header redirect 301 -> http://test.com/keyword
http://test.com/keyword rewrite -> http://test.com/index.php/keyword
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`L` only ends current rule ant causes `mod_rewrite` to loop over your .htaccess all again.

What you need is actually reorder of your rules to keep redirect before rewrites like this:

```
## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.

#rewrite all urls starting with index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php(.*)$ $1 [R=302,L]

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#
## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.
```

Make sure to test it after clearing your browser cache.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm getting exactly the same results. If I try my rules here, and remove the E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization} rule, then it works. BUT removing it in my local test system doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: So what's the URL you are entering in browser and what error are you seeing?

Comment: I'm entering http://test.com/keyword/keyword and get redirected to http://test.com, which is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use ErrorDocument instead of trying to use this with rewrite rules:

```
## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

Comment: I'm not looking for error document. I'm looking for a solution that allows me to redirect http://test.com/index.php/keyword/keyword without affecting anything else.

Comment: I'm confused by the different urls you mention in this question: In one comment you say you want to redirect example.com/keyword/keyword, here you say you want to redirect example.com/index.php/keyword/keyword.
What is the actual url that people type in their browsers? And that should be redirected internally to the index.php script?